# OpenOffice Calc time conversion

Tags: linux, excel, time, openoffice-calc

I was profiling some programs using the "time" command on linux. This outputted its results in a format like this: 1m48.952s

Now I would like to tabulate and graph all my collected data but it's not easy when it's in this format.

I have two questions:
1. Is there a way to easily convert this format into solely pure seconds. Perhaps an OpenOffice Calc function?
2. Is there a way to call my "time" command so that it will output in seconds and not minutes-seconds.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you tagged this with excel, so here's the excel solution:

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND("m",A1)),VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1)), LEFT(A1,FIND("m",A1)-1)*60+MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)+1,FIND("s",A1)-FIND("m",A1)-1))`

It's a simple formula so it will probably translate directly for open office. Here's some sample results:

[image]

As for your second question, [man time](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time) explains that you can `-f FORMAT` your output. Description of how you set the format string is in the link. I believe you want `-f %e` Elapsed real time (in seconds). The default appears to be `%E` Elapsed real time (in [hours:]minutes:seconds).

Comment: Thank you, very much! Yes, I have Excel so it's no problem. :-)